# Rails single table inheritance change type of object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following STI models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
class Unapproved < Question
class Approved < Question
```

If I have a question that is of type `Unapproved`, how can I convert it into of type `Approved`?

Answer (score 4):

See the [`becomes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/becomes) and [`becomes!`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/becomes%21) methods, e.g:

```
Unapproved.first.becomes!(Approved)
```

Comment: I never knew this existed! Great insight! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Rails provides a method for autoswitching, but you should be able to do:

```
Approved.first.update(type: 'Unapproved')
```

OR

```
question = Approved.find(x)
question.type = 'Unapproved'
question.save
```

You could define the autoswitcher yourself in your `Question` class too